# Getting “SyntaxError: [stdin]:27:45: unmatched OUTDENT” in coffeescript

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, if-statement, coffeescript, formatting

I’m using Rails 4.2.3.  I’m attempting to define this function in my coffee script

```
toggle_auto_checkbox -> ()
  if $.trim($('#hometown').val().length > 0 and 
  ($.trim($('#first_name').val().length > 0 or $.trim($('#last_name').val().length > 0) and 
  $('#mySelectBox1 option').filter(':selected').text().length > 0 and   
  $('#mySelectBox2 option').filter(':selected').text().length > 0 and    
  $('#mySelectBox3 option').filter(':selected').text().length > 0 and   
  $('#mySelectBox4 option').filter(':selected').text().length > 0
    $("input.group1").removeAttr("disabled")
  else
    $("input.group1").attr("disabled", true)
```

but it is resulting in the error “SyntaxError: [stdin]:27:45: unmatched OUTDENT” when I try and load the page that includes this coffee script.  What is the issue with the above?

Comment: Check your parentheses. Why do you keep repeating `$('#mySelectBox option').filter(':selected').text().length > 0`?  Why are you calling `$.trim` with boolean arguments? BTW, `$(x)` gives you a jQuery object, not a string, maybe you want to look at `$('#hometown').val()` instead.

Comment: I added in the ".val()" lines and edited the question to reflect that there are different items, but the error remains.  Parens look good to me.  Are you seeing somethign I'm not?

Comment: Look closer at your parentheses; `$.trim($('#hometown').val().length > 0 and ...`, for example, doesn't make sense, maybe you mean `$.trim($('#hometown').val()).length > 0 and ...`. Can't your text editor show you which `)` closes a `(`? Also, trying to cram all that logic into an `if` is a recipe for confusion, you should break it out into a separate function (which can be written out more verbosely) so that you can say `if group1_should_be_enabled() ...`.

Comment: Good call, that's exactly the issue